# Verb dictionary form+よう

Tags: grammar

> ……久しぶりに自分に戻れた。
>   こうして筆を持つのは何ヶ月ぶりか。
>   おそらく次はないだろう。
>   筆はここで止める事にする。
>   私の死後、**これはアキハに渡すよう娘に言いつけた**。
>   アキハがこれを読むかどうかは解らない。
>   だが一度でも目を通したのなら、必ず処分する事。
>   それが私、遠野槙久が我が娘にあてる、ただ一つの遺言である。
>
> After a long time I came back to myself.
>   It's been so many months since I could hold my brush like this.
>   Probably there will not be another time.
>   Now I will stop using the brush.
>   After my death, I will give this to Akiha, so I told my daughter.
>   I do not now if Akiha will read it or not.
>   But, even if you read this one time, make sure to dispose it.
>   This is, Tohono Makihisa, my will that I will pass down to my daughter.

I don't get why よう is used here.
よう means situation, appearance or will to do something so I thought.

> 私の死後、[これは(this notebook) アキハに渡す]>よう(situation, will)娘に言いつけた。

The second part is also confusing because Akiha is the daughter, so he is saying something like:

> After my death, this notebook I will give it to Akiha, so I told my daughter.

Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An easy way to remember this pattern is that it's used when telling someone to do something else, but it's not limited to that (obviously).

```
Aさんに, 私に電話するように伝えてください。
風邪をひかないように気をつけてください。
```

Your example is quite similar.  The translation of which is "I told my daughter to give this notebook to Akiha after my death."  The way it got infused into my brain was we had these dialogues my 2nd or 3rd year, where you called for someone that wasn't home, and told them to call you back (or something else - as seen in my first example).  I think we read those a million times.

Similarly...

```
そうするように頑張ります。
いい人になるように頑張ります。
```

If you wanted to translate all of these in a similar fashion, you'd simply translate the verb dictionary form + ように as "to".  "Tell him to call me".  "Be careful not to get a cold".  "All do my best to do that".  "I'll do my best to become a good person".  Colloquially they might come out quite different though.

Comment: So it could be seen as: The thing that confuses me is that Akiha and the daughter are the same person. So he is saying: After my book, give this book to Akiha, so I instructed my daughter.
But Akiha is also the daughter, it seems like he has another daughter but he does not.

Edit. I found out that 娘 is also young lady, Miss, unmarried women ecc.
He has a little girls who is his servant. Now it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: Well, it's not uncommon to refer to people in 1st or 3rd person (including yourself) in Japanese, but that does make the sentence sound wonky, unless, as you stated 娘 is someone else... some context before this could help, but if it makes sense to you, that works. ;)